# Unexpected behavior for two backend apps deployed in GKE with the same config

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

**PROBLEM BACKGROUND**

I don't have another word to describe the behavior of the deployment I found in my workplace kubernetes deployment,

We have five kubernetes deployment for backend apps using Koa.js, one development deployment, two staging deployment, two production deployment.

The API is separated into two versions, which it reads by the folder name,  v3 and v4. Both versions of koa router access the same controller and service function, both routers identical, the differences is just there are additional routes in the v4 than v3.

Both production  deployment  differ by their name only. The rest of the deployment config remains the same between (eg: isafe-prod-android-api, isafe-prod-ios-api). Both deployment also share the same configmap and secrets.

---

**PROBLEM EXPLANATION**

The weird behavior starts when i have assignment to adjust an endpoint to download image from 2 different cloud oss, 1 from GCP bucket, 1 from Alibaba OSS.

the endpoint expected behavior was intended to handle dynamic checking and download image between both bucket.

for example: I want to download older image using this endpoint, the endpoint should check the bucket from Alibaba OSS first, when the image not found there, the function that handle this checking should just return false instead of throwing error, but if found in the alibaba oss, it returns the image and redirects to the url.

The same occurs if the image not found in the alibaba, the function should just return false, and continue the process to check the image from GCP bucket functions, if found, then redirect to image url, but if the image not found in both bucket, then it should throw error as its response that image not exist in bot bucket.

The expected behavior occurs in  development and first production deployment (ios backend). The unexpected behavior occurs in the production deployment for android backend, which has the same config with ios, and just different in naming.

Unexpected behaviors:

1. on the ios production deployment, it works as expected either in v3 and v4, when sending image name that are not exist in both bucket, it returns expected response, also when checking image that only exist in either bucket, it returns the image without problem.

The problem occurs when trying to hit the endpoint from production deployment for android in v4, I tried to get an image that exist in the GCP bucket and not exist in Alibaba OSS, the expected behavior is that it should just return the image, since it exists in the GCP. But what happens is that it throws the error from alibaba oss in XML format, as if the "return false" error handler never been executed.

---

**PROBLEM EVIDENCES AND CODE SNIPPETS**
**Main problem evidence**

[image from production for android v4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT1Qp.png)

This doesn't happen in the production deployment for ios. Both use the same docker image version from the same container registry.

The function that handles the checking image and download itself already in a try catch block, and it should just return false instead of throwing error.

**Here is the code snippet for the logic**:

[Download Image v4 logic code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60ptm.png)

**This is the service logic to check the image from Aliyun OSS**:

[Download Image service logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eefZO.png)

also when looking up at the kubernetes log, I found such error, which always occured after I send request to `/api/v4/images/:filename` on production android deployment without any trace which code that caused this.

I investigated the error with this on forums, but not found any clue at all.

**Unexplained error evidence**:

[Parse Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fdWb.png)

---

Any recommendation or suggestions, highly appreciated

Comment: @GregAskew Thanks for the reviewed and formatting